# A simple question about *-homomorphism in C*-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, spectral-theory, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ and $B$ be C*-algebra, $h\colon A\rightarrow B$ is *-homomorphism.

**If $a\in A_{\operatorname{sa}}$, then $\operatorname{sp}(h(a))\backslash \{0\}\subset \operatorname{sp}(a)\backslash\{0\}$. Here, $A_{\operatorname{sa}}$ denotes all the self adjoint elements in $A$**

How to prove this inclusion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This result holds in more general case of Banach algebras.

By $A_+:=A\oplus_1 \mathbb{C}$ we denote unitalization of Banach algebra $A$. Multiplication in $A_+$ is given by the formula
$$
(a,\lambda)(b,\mu )
=(ab+\lambda b+\mu a,\lambda\mu)
$$
The algebra $A_+$ is unital with unit $e_{A_+}=(0_A,1_{\mathbb{C}})$.

For a given Banach algebra homomorphism $h:A\to B:a\mapsto h(a)$ we have well defined unitalization $h_+:A_+\to B_+:(a,\lambda)\mapsto (h(a),\lambda)$. Clearly $h_+$ is a unital homomorphism, i.e. preserve units. We also use the notation $rg_A(a)=\mathbb{C}\setminus sp_A(a)$

> **Lemma 1.** For a given unital Banach algebra $A$ we have $sp_{A_+}(a)=sp_A(a)\cup\{0\}$ for all $a\in A$.

**Proof.** Let $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$.  Let $b\in A$ be inverse element of $a-\lambda e_A$, then it is easy to check that $b-\lambda^{-1}(e_{A_+}-e_A)\in A_+$ is the inverse element of $a-\lambda e_{A_+}$. Conversely, if $c\in A_+$ is the inverse element of $a-\lambda e_{A_+}$, then $e_Ac\in A$ is the inverse element of $a-\lambda e_A$.

From previous paragraph it follows that $rg_A(a)\setminus \{0\}=rg_{A_+}(a)$, hence $sp_{A_+}(a)=sp_A(a)\cup\{0\}$.

> **Lemma 2.** Let $h:A\to B$ be a unital homomorphism of unital Banach algebras, then $sp_B(h(a))\subset sp_A(a)$ for all $a\in A$

**Proof.** Let $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$. Assume $b\in A$ is the inverse element of $a-\lambda e_A$. It is easy to check that $h(b)\in B$ is the inverse element of $h(a)-\lambda e_B$. This means that $rg_A(a)\subset rg_{B}(h(a))$, hence $sp_B(h(a))\subset sp_A(a)$.

> **Proposition.** Let $h:A\to B$ be a (not necessarily unital!) homomorphism of unital Banach algebras, then $sp_B(h(a))\cup\{0\}\subset sp_A(a)\cup\{0\}$.

**Proof.** Consider unital homomorphism $h_+:A_+\to B_+$. By lemma 2 we have $sp_{B_+}(h_+(a))\subset sp_{A_+}(a)$ for all $a\in A_+$. Recall that $h_+(a)=ha(a)$ for all $a\in A$, so by lemma 1 we get that $sp_B(h(a))\cup\{0\}\subset sp_A(a)\cup\{0\}$.

Comment: The word "Banach" can be removed, right?  It is just a fact about algebra homomorphisms.

Comment: I didn't thought in this direction. Yes that result is purely algebraic.