# left inverse operator and the spectrum

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, ring-theory, operator-theory

Let $D$ be the left inverse bounded operator from $Y$ to $X$ (Banach spaces) of a bounded operator $A$ from $X$ to $Y$, Iam trying to find the spectrum of the operator $AD$ ..
My attempt is to work on matrices and to see if I can generalize the result for any bounded operators. I tried different types of matrix and they all gave me different eigenvalues so I don’t know if I can say that the spectrum of $AD$ is the set of complex numbers?

I tried for operators generally, I know that $D$ is left inverse so that $DA=I_X$ but I cant permute $D$ or $A$ since I don’t know if $D$ is invertible or not and that similarly for $A$..
For the spectrum of $DA$ is it the set ${1}$ because $DA=I_X$ ?
Any help would be appreciated ..

Answer (score 1):

If $AD$ is invertible, then $ADR=I$ for some $R$, and now $D=DADR=DR$, so $AD=I$. In this case, $$\sigma(AD)=\sigma(I)=\{1\}.$$

If $AD$ is not invertible (so, in particular, $0\in\sigma(AD)$), then [we still know that](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1584573/22857)  $$\{0\}\cup\sigma(DA)=\{0\}\cup\sigma(AD).$$
If follows, since $\sigma(DA)=\{1\}$, that $$\sigma(AD)=\{0,1\}.$$

The above has nothing to do with operators nor Banach spaces: the argument holds in any unital ring (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/542995/22857) for a purely algebraic argument).

Comment: Thank you Mr Martin for you help, so I think at the end the spectrum of AD is equal to 1, I don't understand that why 0 is included here?

Comment: Having $0$ in the spectrum means precisely "not invertible". Or, if you want, if $0\not\sigma(AD)$, then $AD$ is invertible.

Comment: (sorry, I meant to type "$0\not\in\sigma(AD)$" above)

Comment: very clear, thank you very much Mr Martin..